# Mouse not moving

Tags: mouse

I have a Logitech mouse on Acer, running 14.1 LTS.
I have found this 'answer' for my problem: "Wireless and optical mice, as well as touchpads on laptops, may need to "wake up" before they start working. They automatically go to sleep when not in use to save battery power. To wake up your mouse or touchpad, you can click on a mouse button or wiggle the mouse."
Is there a way to prevent the mouse from going to sleep?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

then try to move your mouse cursor using the pad of laptop